# Saving a file in Android

Tags: java, android, file, stream, streamwriter

I have the following code:

```
    btnSaveTrip.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (showLog != null && showLog.getText().toString().length() > 0) {
                File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/tc");
                if (!folder.exists()) {
                    folder.mkdir();
                }
                String externalStoragePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
                final File file = new File(externalStoragePath + "/tc/strip.tcl");
                try {
                    if (file.exists()) {
                        new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                        .setTitle("File Already Exist")
                        .setMessage("Do you want to overwrite the file?")
                        .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
                                outputStream.write(showLog.getText().toString().getBytes());
                                Toast.makeText (getActivity(), file.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        })
                        .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                // do nothing
                            }
                        })
                        .show();
                    }
                    else {
                        outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
                        outputStream.write(showLog.getText().toString().getBytes());
                        Toast.makeText (getActivity(), file.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
                catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText (getActivity(), "error in try", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                finally {
                    if(outputStream!=null) {
                        try {
                            outputStream.close();
                            Toast.makeText (getActivity(), "file closed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                        catch (IOException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            Toast.makeText (getActivity(), "error in finally catch", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText (getActivity(), "empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

What I am looking to do is:

When the button is clicked:

1) Check to make the data is not null or empty (**Working fine**):

```
if (showLog != null && showLog.getText().toString().length() > 0) {
```

2) Check to make sure the folder exists, if not create the folder (**Working fine**):

```
            File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/tc");
            if (!folder.exists()) {
                folder.mkdir();
            }
```

3) Before writing the data to the file, ensure it doesn't already exist. If it does exist, prompt the user to see if it can be overwritten. If the user chooses YES then overwrite the file but if the user chooses NO then add a "1" at the end of the filename and save it. (**NOT WORKING and need help**)

I am getting an error for the following line:

```
outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
outputStream.write(showLog.getText().toString().getBytes());
```

Error:

> Unhandled exception type FileNotFoundException
>
> --> (Surround with try/catch)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In answer to part 3), I've edited your code to work properly for you. Most of the code you had was correctly written there was just a couple of issues. I also moved the code to write a new file into a new method `writeFile()` in order to avoid replicating code and to make it easier to keep track of what's going on:

```
btnSaveTrip.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (showLog != null && showLog.getText().toString().length() > 0) {
            File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/TollCulator");
            if (!folder.exists()) {
                folder.mkdir();
            }
            String externalStoragePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
            final File file = new File(externalStoragePath + "/TollCulator/strip.tcl");
            if (file.exists()) {
                new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                .setTitle("File Already Exist")
                .setMessage("Do you want to overwrite the existing file?")
                .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        writeFile(file);
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                })
                .show();
            } else {
                writeFile(file);
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText (getActivity(), "empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
});

// ...

private void writeFile(File file){
    try {
        outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
        outputStream.write(showLog.getText().toString().getBytes());
        Toast.makeText (getActivity(), file.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if(outputStream!=null) {
            try {
                outputStream.close();
                Toast.makeText (getActivity(), "file closed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText (getActivity(), "error in finally catch", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

1)

```
File tcDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"tc");
tcDir.mkdirs();
File file = new File(tcdir, "strip.tcl");
```

The first line creates a file object called tc in the external storage directoy.  The second line creates it on disk, with any missing parents.  The third line creates a file object inside that directory

2)You seem to be doing that-  you create a file output stream and write to it like you're doing.

3)Before writing the file, cal file.exists().  If it exists, you need to pop up a AlertDialog.  If they hit the yes button of the dialog you write a file.  If they choose the no button, you do nothing.  It would be best to put all of the writing code into a separate function so it can be called in both the dialog click code and in the !exists code here.

Comment: Before writing the file instead of giving it pre defined name, can I prompt the user to name the file?

Comment: Of course you can, its just more details.  Pop up a dialog box with an edit text in it for filename and replace strip.tcl with the string they type in.